# c# inherit 2 classes at once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, custom-attributes

I have a situation here in C# 4.0 that would benefit from multiple inheritance of objects.

Example:

AuthorizeAttribute and ApiController are MS standard base classes.  I would like to extend each with the code from a class I wrote so I can do the following:

```
[AuthorizeAttributeTotalAccess]
public class TemplateController : ApiControllerBase
{
    // ...
}

public class AuthorizeAttributeTotalAccess : AuthorizeAttributeBase
{
    // ...
}

public class AuthorizeAttributeTotalAccess : AuthorizeAttributeBase
{
    protected virtual ClaimsPrincipal CurrentUser
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal; }
    }
    protected virtual IEnumerable<dynamic> CurrentUserClaims
    {
        get
        {
            return from c in CurrentUser.Identities.First().Claims
                    select new
                    {
                        c.Type,
                        c.Value
                    };
        }
    }

    // ...
}

public class ApiControllerBase : ApiController
{
    protected virtual ClaimsPrincipal CurrentUser
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal; }
    }
    protected virtual IEnumerable<dynamic> CurrentUserClaims
    {
        get
        {
            return from c in CurrentUser.Identities.First().Claims
                    select new
                    {
                        c.Type,
                        c.Value
                    };
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Any idea how to achieve this?  As you can see, both base classes contain the exact same code yet each base class **has to** inherit the standard MS classes which are different.

Comment: There's only a few lines, but you could move them to separate, static helper methods that both classes call into.

Comment: .NET does not support multiple inheritance. Period.  You could encapsulate one or both of the two classes and pass-through the methods but you can't use pure inheritance on both.

Comment: I had a similar situation as the code you provided (it may be incomplete). I had set a custom `Principal` in my BaseController. Then, from the `AuthorizeAttributeTotalAccess`, you can overwrite the principal in your controller. That way, you can stop dreaming about multiple inheritance as it's not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not completely seamless, but one option you have for cases like this where you want to provide common helper methods is using extension methods. This is not exactly what extension methods are designed for, so the convenience of not having to wrap the calls in some shared class is offset by the potential confusion to other developers looking at your code and getting confused about where these methods are coming from.

```
public interface IUserHelperMethods
{
    // Empty marker interface
}

public static class UserHelperExtensions
{
    public static ClaimsPrincipal GetCurrentUser(this IUserHelperMethods)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
    }
}

public class ApiControllerBase : ApiController, IUserHelperMethods
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        this.GetCurrentUser();
    }
}

public class AuthorizeAttributeTotalAccess : AuthorizeAttributeBase, IUserHelperMethods
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        this.GetCurrentUser();
    }
}
```

Also note that I had to change your property to a Get...() method as C# doesn't support extension properties.

Comment: Good answer. However, in this case it would probably make more sense to put the extension method on `HttpContextBase` since it is already passed to both the `ApiController` and `AuthorizeAttribute`.

Comment: Good point, yes - if there's an existing type that's common to both scenarios then that makes most sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to inherit from two classes in C#. That is not the same as an inheritance chain where you inherit from a class that inherits from a class.

Still, if you look at the C# spec, there's no explanation of why. If you talk to some of the team, they will explain that it has to do with re-casting a class up the inheritance tree. In short, it has to do with utter complexity.

> This feature is supported in C++.

FYI: there is no plan to ever add this feature to C#.